# Unable to get the frog object to jump in the Defold getting started tutorial

Tags: defold

I've completed the [Defold tutorial](http://www.defold.com/tutorials/getting-started/) upto Step5 and also the first 7 points of Step6. However, I when I hit space the frog object does not jump. I keep seeing the below messages in the console.

```
WARNING:DLIB: Failed to send announce message (-22)
```

Also, if I place the frog object at some height above the ground it does not 'fall' but just runs its animation.

What could be wrong?  I don't think that I can copy the entire contents here as there is so much, can anyone share a working source for the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the hero.script component to the hero game object as per [this](https://forum.defold.com/t/unable-to-get-the-frog-object-to-jump-in-the-defold-getting-started-tutorial-solved/1230) answer on the Defold forum